# Why my user is not being loaded with a valid jwt token?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am having an issue trying to authenticate a user. I have to three reducers logout register and login which they work fine or at least it seems that way. The issue is with the token that contains the user data that i am passing to the register and login functions.

So i have the following util function setAuthToken.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const setAuthToken = token => {
    if(token){
        axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'] = token;
    } else {
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common['x-atuh-token'];
    }
}

export default setAuthToken
```

Then i have the following slice:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import setAuthToken from '../../utils/setAuthToken';

import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated: false,
    loading: true,
    user: null,
    error: null
}

export const loadUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/loadUser',
  async ({ rejectWithValue }) => {

    if(localStorage.token){
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }

    try {
      const res = axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/auth');
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
)

export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/registerUser',
  async (newUser, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      };
      const body = JSON.stringify(newUser);
      const response = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/users',
        body,
        config
      );
      dispatch(loadUser());
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);


export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk('auth/login', async ({ email, password }, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
  const body = { email, password };

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  try {
    const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/auth', body, config);

    dispatch(loadUser());
    console.log(body)
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
  }
});






export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logoutUser:(state, action) => {
      state.token = null;
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.user = null;
    }
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [registerUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [registerUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.token = localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = null;
      
    },
    [registerUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
    [loadUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [loadUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = false;
    },
    [loadUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.error = action.payload;

    },
    [loginUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [loginUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.token = localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.loading = false;
      state.user = action.payload.user;
    },
    [loginUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    }
  }
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { logoutUser } = userSlice.actions


export default userSlice.reducer
```

For for some reason there might be an error in my loadUser function in the way i am loading the user with the token.
If i register or login i get the right information in my args object that contain `name` `email` and `password`
But the state is not the correct.
So the action type is correct `user/register/fulfilled`
But the state is incorrect:
I get a token that is invalid in jwt, isAuthenticated is false and should be true, and the token that the user has is also invalid.

This is my component where i am dispatching the loadUser function:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { registerUser } from '../reducers/auth/authSlice';

//Material UI
import {Grid, Container, Box, Button, FormControl, InputLabel, Input, FormHelperText } from '@mui/material'

function Register() {
    
    const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.user.isAuthenticated);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [ formData, setFormData ] = useState({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        password2: ''
    })

    const { name, email, password, password2 } = formData; 

    const onChange = e => setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (password !== password2) {
          console.log('Passwords do not match');
        } else {
          const newUser = {
            name: formData.name,
            email: formData.email,
            password: formData.password,
          };
          dispatch(registerUser(newUser));
        }
      };

      if(isAuthenticated){
        return <Navigate to="/dashboard"/>;
      }

    return (
    <Container>
        <Box p={4}>
            <Grid container  >
                <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
                    <Grid item md={12}>
                        <FormControl>
                            <InputLabel htmlFor="name">Name</InputLabel>
                            <Input 
                            type='text' 
                            id='name' 
                            name='name'
                            value={name}
                            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                            <FormHelperText>Insert your complete name</FormHelperText>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid> 
                    <Grid item md={12}>
                        <FormControl>
                            <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email</InputLabel>
                            <Input 
                            id='email' 
                            type='email' 
                            name='email'
                            value={email}
                            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                            <FormHelperText>Insert your email</FormHelperText>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item md={12}>    
                        <FormControl>
                            <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
                            <Input 
                            id="password" 
                            type='password' 
                            name='password'
                            value={password}
                            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                            <FormHelperText>Insert your password (must have at least 6 characters)</FormHelperText>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item md={12}>    
                        <FormControl>
                            <InputLabel htmlFor="password2">Confirm Password</InputLabel>
                            <Input 
                            id="password2" 
                            type='password'
                            name='password2' 
                            value={password2}
                            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                            <FormHelperText>Insert your password (must have at least 6 characters)</FormHelperText>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item md={12}>    
                        <Button type='submit' variant="contained" color="primary">
                            Register
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </form>
            </Grid>
        </Box>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Register
```

and finally the loadUser comes rejected:
`user/loaded/rejected`

With the following error:

```
name:"TypeError"
message:"Cannot destructure property 'rejectWithValue' of '_ref' as it is undefined."
stack:"TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'rejectWithValue' of '_ref' as it is undefined.
```

Comment: Please only include relevant code, and explain your problem clear and simple. I've skimmed through your question and It's not even clear to me what part is generating the error.

Answer (score 0):

You're not following the proper thunk api format. From the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk):

> The payloadCreator function will be called with two arguments:
>
> - `arg`: a single value, containing the first parameter that was passed to the thunk action creator when it was dispatched. This is useful for passing in values like item IDs that may be needed as part of the request. If you need to pass in multiple values, pass them together in an object when you dispatch the thunk, like dispatch(fetchUsers({status: 'active', sortBy: 'name'})).
> - `thunkAPI`: an object containing all of the parameters that are normally passed to a Redux thunk function, as well as additional options.

The error message shows that you're trying to access `arg.rejectWithValue` (which you clearly don't want to).

This means you're missing the first argument from createAsyngThink. Even if you don't want to use it, you need to leave it there to be able to use the second argument (`thunkAPI` that contains your `rejectWithValue`) :

```js
export const loadUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/loadUser',
  async ( arg, { rejectWithValue }) => { // you're missing the arg here

    if(localStorage.token){
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }

    try {
      const res = axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/auth');
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
)
```